# Swapping words in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

Here is two sentence what do they mean

Posted right at my front doorstep

Posted right to my front doorstep

Comment: Ideally, you would include [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like what you think they mean. Also, complete sentences would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference.

> Posted right **at** my front doorstep.

means you mailed *something* at your front doorstep for delivery someplace else.  This is possible where the mailman collects fully franked mail which is left inside your mailbox.

> Posted right **to** my front doorstep.

means someone sent *something* and it was *delivered* to your from door.